# Protect passwords in CI environment

Tags: jenkins, bamboo

So it is a common situation that you want to use your CI environment such as Jenkins or Bamboo to deploy to servers. This also means that you need to store endpoint credentials somewhere.

What is the best practice to do this? Having passwords as plain-text in text files is of course the easy route, but often not possible.

Comment: I'd say that is pretty broad question... injection via environment variables comes to my mind. That's how many people do it (AFAIK) with Jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Maven to do the deployment you can encrypt your passwords, see: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html

Answer (score 0):

We generally use [MaskPasswords plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin) for jenkins and I am not sure of bamboo

Comment: Setting build plan variables in Bamboo is the way to go. The tool will mask variable values when expanded if *password* is part of the variable name.

Comment: @KenBrittain: passwords are exposed at run time in Bamboo. You can view them via  `ps`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Jenkins credentials plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin) to store your passwords; Jenkins encrypts them in the configuration stored on disk.  Note that it is possible to decrypt the passwords, so make sure your Jenkins configuration files are adequately protected.